# Synchronous CORS XHR 302 redirect fails, but asynchronous works

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, soundcloud

Firefox seems to be the only browser that doesn't throw an error when performing this synchronous request, any idea why?

```js
// Make sure to have your JS console open when you run this
var url = '//api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=83f67039ae0c3790030d256cb9029678';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false); // SYNCHRONOUS
xhr.onload = alert.bind(null, 'Loaded');
xhr.send(null);
```

Performing an almost identical asynchronous XMLHttpRequest results in no errors and the request completing as expected:

```js
// Make sure to have your JS console open when you run this
var url = '//api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=83f67039ae0c3790030d256cb9029678';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true); // ASYNCHRONOUS
xhr.onload = alert.bind(null, 'Loaded');
xhr.send(null);
```

From what I can understand:

- The [SoundCloud API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) returns proper CORS headers.
- The [SoundCloud resolve API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) performs a 302 redirect to `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json`.
- If the request is performed ***asynchronously*** it will successfully follow the redirect and complete.
- If the request is performed **synchronously** then it will fail with the following errors in the console (sans Firefox):

  - Chrome: "NetworkError: A network error occurred."
  - Opera: "NetworkError: A network error occurred."
  - Safari: "XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests."

Can anyone explain *why* the synchronous request is failing? And why it is failing with such an odd error especially since the same request works when performed asynchronously? Why does that parameter make a difference? Is it a known bug with Firefox or with the WebKit/Blink crowd?

**Edit**: I've [opened a new issue on Chrome's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327014) as no one has yet been able to point out anything in the spec that would properly explain this behavior. I will likely open a similar issue for WebKit when I get a chance.

Comment: @apsillers you're right, I've simplified the title. Firefox works for both sync and async requests. Other browsers only work with the async requests and fail with the sync version.

Comment: I looked over the XHR and [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-0), and the only semi-legitimate failure reason I could find was "`If for some reason the user agent does not want to make the request terminate this algorithm and set the cross-origin request status to network error.`" (with similar wording in the [redirect steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#redirect-steps)). Maybe those browsers consider a synchronous 302 redirect suitable grounds for termination. That seems pretty crazy to me, but I could see the concern over not allowing redirects while the UI is frozen.

Comment: @apsillers interesting. It seems very strange to me that a request can fail or succeed based on the synchronicity of the request. It would seem important to know that synchronous requests will fail regardless of any other variables simply due to a vendor's decision about HTTP 302 redirects. I would have expected the spec to say something like "Any request that works asynchronously **MUST** work synchronously. The synchronicity **MUST NOT** affect the outcome of the request."

Comment: I agree, it seems very strange; the passage I quoted was intended to offer freedom to allow blocking blacklisted URLs or HTTPS-to-HTTP messages (neither of which apply here). The only other cases I know where sync vs. async makes a difference are 1) `withCredentials` is not allow in sync requests (but that raises an error at property-set-time, not at fetch-time) and also 2) Firefox (at least) disallows `Blob`, `File`, and `ArrayBufferView` objects as the arguments of a synchoronus `send`, to discourage sending large pieces of binary data synchronously.

Comment: @apsillers so what happens if the synchronous request is performed inside a Web Worker? There is no need to perform the request asynchronously when you're already in the context of another thread. I will have to test whether or not the request still fails in that situation.

Comment: @apsillers it looks like synchronous requests **do** work properly when executed inside a Web Worker.

Comment: @apsillers If you get a chance, please check out (and/or star) the [new issue #327014 I just filed on the Chromium bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327014).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a deliberate choice made in order to discourage the use of synchronous requests:

- w3 web apps mailing list: [Disable new response types for sync XHR in Window context](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011OctDec/0833.html)
- w3 bug: [Investigate if synchronous XHR in window context should not support new XHR responseTypes](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14773)
- Webkit: [Synchronous XHR in window context should not support new XHR responseTypes for HTTP(S) requests](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72154)
- Mozilla: [Investigate if synchronous XHR in window context should not support new XHR responseTypes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701787)

From what I can gleem, IE never seems to have supported it in the first place.

Comment: Unless it's in the spec, it's a bug with the vendor.

Comment: I also don't see anything about 302 redirects. These are all about trying to access `xhr.response` based on the `xhr.responseType`.

Comment: @idbehold You are right; rereading my links, they were discussing whether to disable sync CORS XHR completely, but that did not go anywhere.   Parsing the CORS and XHR2 specs for a while now, your situation seems to be in-spec. However, I found this regarding Chrome: "I added the CORS redirect handling to WebKit a while back. It was only implemented for asynchronous requests." - [Chromium bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154967#c9)

Comment: If you get a chance, please check out (and/or star) the [new issue #327014 I just filed on the Chromium bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327014).